# If TreeSet arranges data from oldest to newest which class orders them from newest to oldest

Tags: java, android, sorting

I have the following code in an note taking app. The notes are sorted by keys.
TreeSet puts the oldest first. I would like to do the contrary. Which class to use?

```
    //retrieve data, map unordered data collection with a key and a value
    Map<String, ?> notesMap = notePrefs.getAll();
    //get a list of all the keys of the notes, keySet-return all Keys without order, TreeSet-sorts data
    SortedSet<String> keys =new TreeSet<String>(notesMap.keySet());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) which will behave opposite as default one. Then you pass it's instance in constructor of various containers.